# Go言語におけるインクリメントについて

Tags: go

main関数で

```
var count int
var listcount []int
```

を宣言して
以下の `replaceFileContents` 関数の中身の最後にインクリメントで

```
count++
listcount = append(listcount, count)
```

を書いて実行したのですが、

```
fmt.Println("置換したファイル合計数は"+len(listcount))
```

で、`0`が表示されてしまいます。値の受け渡しがうまくできてないのでしょうか？エラーは出ていないのですが、どこが問題なのか原因がわかりにくく。

```
func replaceFileContents(path string, before, after []byte, count int, listcount []int) error {
    read, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if bytes.Contains(read, before) {
        newContents := bytes.Replace(read, before, after, -1)
        err = ioutil.WriteFile(path, newContents, os.ModePerm)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("置換したファイル:" + path)
    count++
    listcount = append(listcount, count)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var count int
    var listcount []int

    root := input("ファイルパス")
    before := []byte(input("置換前文字列"))
    after := []byte(input("置換後文字列"))

    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        matched, err := filepath.Match("*log.xml", fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if fi.IsDir() || !matched {
            //if fi.IsDir() || filepath.Ext(fi.Name()) != ".xml" {
            return nil
        }

        return replaceFileContents(path, before, after, count, listcount)
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("置換したファイル合計数は"+len(listcount))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Goの値渡し／ポインタ（参照）渡しに関する理解が不足しています。
以下の簡単な比較コードを試して、違いを確かめてください。

```
package main
import "fmt"

func addToList1(list []int, x int) {
    list = append(list, x)
}

func addToList2(list *[]int, x int) {
    *list = append(*list, x)
}

func main() {
    {
        var list1 []int
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            addToList1(list1, i)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Count = %d\n", len(list1))
    }
    {
        var list2 []int
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            addToList2(&list2, i)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Count = %d\n", len(list2))
    }
}
```

`addToList1()`関数は値渡しなので、仮引数の`list`は、上記の呼び出し例では`main()`関数内の`list1`をコピーした別物になります。
仮引数はローカル変数の一種であり、仮引数に対する変更は実引数に影響を及ぼさず、関数を抜けると捨てられます。
`addToList2()`関数はポインタ渡しなので、仮引数の`list`は、上記の呼び出し例では`main()`関数内の`list2`のアドレスを保持しています。
ポインタを`*`演算子でデリファレンスすることで、実体への参照を得ることができ、オブジェクトの読み取りと書き換えが可能となります。

配列のようなサイズの大きいデータ構造は、毎回コピーするとコストが大きいので、読み取りだけであっても基本的にポインタ渡しにします。